# How do you select every n-th row from mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a series of values in a database that I need to pull to create a line chart. Because i dont require high resolution I would like to resample the data by selecting every 5th row from the database.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, [column name] 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT @row :=0) r, [table name] 
    ) ranked 
WHERE rownum % [n] = 1
```

Comment: Can someone provide more information about how this works? For instance the question asked for every 5th row and there is no mention of 5 in the answer.

Comment: @Crazometer replace `[n]` in the query with 5 to get every 5th row.

Comment: To expand on this, what if you didn't want to start with the first row but the 2nd for example?

Comment: @HPWD you would replace `@row :=0` with `@row :=2`

Comment: @BinarWeb no, you would change the `= 1` to `= 2`

Answer (score 62):

You could try [mod](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) 5 to get rows where the ID is multiple of 5.  (Assuming you have some sort of ID column that's sequential.)

```
select * from table where table.id mod 5 = 0;
```

Comment: Also assuming you have no gaps in the sequence, due to delete or rollback.

Comment: This would work for the most part but does not account for deleted rows.

Comment: Simple and brilliant for some testing :-)

Comment: This makes sense if your select retrieves all the data. If you have additional criteria in your select, then it would be difficult to say what data (if any) it would retrieve.

Answer (score 25):

Since you said you're using MySQL, you can use [user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html) to create a continuous row numbering.  You do have to put that in a derived table (subquery) though.

```
SET @x := 0;
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT (@x:=@x+1) AS x, mt.* FROM mytable mt ORDER BY RAND()) t
WHERE x MOD 5 = 0;
```

I added `ORDER BY RAND()` to get a pseudorandom sampling, instead of allowing every fifth row of the unordered table to be in the sample every time.

---

An anonymous user tried to edit this to change `x MOD 5 = 0` to `x MOD 5 = 1`. I have changed it back to my original.

For the record, one can use any value between 0 and 4 in that condition, and there's no reason to prefer one value over another.

Comment: I was updating my answer to this, and you beat me to it!  Good thinking.

Comment: unfortunately, this slows down the execution by at least x100 when working with many entries

Answer (score 10):

```
SET @a = 0;
SELECT * FROM t where (@a := @a + 1) % 2 = 0;
```

Comment: This works great for partitioning an arbitrary, read-only table for parallel processing of the rows, and the syntax is super easy to read and understand.  You just need to add an ORDER BY on the primary key column to ensure each row is returned just once.

Answer (score 2):

I had been looking for something like this.  The answer of Taylor and Bill led me to improve upon their ideas.

table data1 has fields read_date, value
we want to select every 2d record from a query limited by a read_date range
the name of the derived table is arbitrary and here is called DT

query:

```
 SET @row := 0;
  SELECT * FROM  ( SELECT @row := @row +1 AS rownum, read_date, value  FROM data1  
  WHERE  read_date>= 1279771200 AND read_date <= 1281844740 ) as DT WHERE MOD(rownum,2)=0
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for this. I needed to somehow check if a certain column in a log table for stored procedures had the same value every second time. Like 'proc starting', 'proc ending'. The sql below will result with 1 if everything is ok.
`SET @row := 0;
SELECT count(distinct Message) FROM (
SELECT @row := @row +1 AS rownum, Message
FROM operations.EventLog
WHERE LogTime > now() - interval 6 hour
and ProcedureName = 'Do_CDR'
) as DT
WHERE MOD(rownum,2)=0;`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MariaDB 10.2, MySQL 8 or later, you can do this more efficiency, and I think more clearly, using [common table expressions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/common-table-expressions/) and [window functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions/).

```
WITH ordering AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS n, example.* 
    FROM example ORDER BY name
)
SELECT * FROM ordering WHERE MOD(n, 5) = 0;
```

Conceptually, this creates a temporary table with the contents of the `example` table ordered by the `name` field, adds an additional field called `n` which is the row number, and then fetches only those rows with numbers which are exactly divisible by 5, i.e. every 5th row.  In practice, the database engine is often able to optimise this better than that.  But even if it doesn't optimise it any further, I think it's clearer than using [user variables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-defined-variables/) iteratively as you had to in earlier versions of MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM ( 
    SELECT @row := @row +1 AS rownum, posts.*
    FROM (
        SELECT @row :=0) r, posts
    ) ranked
WHERE rownum %3 = 1
```

where posts is my table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query,

```
set @n=2; <!-- nth row -->
select * from (SELECT t.*, 
       @rowid := @rowid + 1 AS ID
  FROM TABLE t, 
       (SELECT @rowid := 0) dummy) A where A.ID mod @n = 0;
```

or you can replace **n** with your **nth value**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require the row number in the result set you can simplify the query.

```
SELECT 
    [column name] 
FROM
    (SELECT @row:=0) temp, 
    [table name] 
WHERE (@row:=@row + 1) % [n] = 1
```

Replace the following placeholders:

1. Replace `[column name]` with a list of columns you need to fetch.
2. Replace `[table name]` with the name of your table.
3. Replace `[n]` with a number. e.g. if you need every 5th row, replace it with 5

Comment: Thanks, it's close but you're better off doing this: select name from (SELECT @row:=-1) temp, t where (@row:=@row + 1) % 1 = 0; This has two advantages. First, regardless of n, you always get the first row and second, if you make n = 1, you get all values rather than none. (Two changes: the -1 in row: =   -   1 and  n = 0 instead of n = 1)