# What does := mean?

Tags: mysql

In response to another question here on stackoverflow ([How do you select every n-th row from mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858746/how-do-you-select-every-n-th-row-from-mysql)), someone supplied this answer:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT @row := @row +1 AS rownum, [column name]
FROM ( SELECT @row :=0) r, [table name] ) ranked WHERE rownum % [n] = 1
```

Could someone provide or point me to more information about the syntax usage here.  I'm not familiar with the use of `:=`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html:

"For SET, either = or := can be used as the assignment operator.

You can also assign a value to a user variable in statements other than SET. In this case, the assignment operator must be := and not = because = is treated as a comparison operator in non-SET statements:

```
mysql> SET @t1=0, @t2=0, @t3=0;
mysql> SELECT @t1:=(@t2:=1)+@t3:=4,@t1,@t2,@t3;
+----------------------+------+------+------+
| @t1:=(@t2:=1)+@t3:=4 | @t1  | @t2  | @t3  |
+----------------------+------+------+------+
|                    5 |    5 |    1 |    4 |
+----------------------+------+------+------+
```

"

Answer (score 2):

`a = b` in MySQL compares `a` to `b` and returns `true` if they're equal, or `false` otherwise. `@a := b`, on the other hand, *sets* the value of `@a` to `b`.

Basically, `=` is the comparison operator ("is equal to"), and `:=` is the assignment operator ("set equal to").

**EDIT:** I just found out that you can use `=` as the assignment operator in `SET` statements, as there's no such thing as comparisons in those. In `SELECT` statements, you have to use `:=` for assignment.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like it's exactly the same as an =.