# what does adding ranked to a mysql query do?

Tags: database, mysql

What does adding ranked to a mysql query do?

I'm trying code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858746/how-do-you-select-every-n-th-row-from-mysql)

SELECT * FROM ( SELECT @row := @row +1 AS rownum, [column name] FROM ( SELECT @row :=0) r, [table name] ) ranked WHERE rownum % [n] = 1

Comment: ...you're going to have to be a bit more specific here, i feel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"ranked" is an alias that you're giving to your sub-select. You're just omitting the "AS" keyword, which is allowed in MySQL.

Example: SELECT name from MyTable AS table1

Answer (score 2):

Nothing, apparently, as "ranked" isn't a MySQL keyword that I can find. Did you possibly mean "ordered by"?