# Selecting each Nth row does not work

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

I developed a SQL command in [my SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/e2f83/2). MySQL Server is set to Version 5.1.61 because my server runs 5.5.31-0+wheezy1. I copied the Schema to my server and created a PHP script that executes the code (with help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/858809/1798015)). But my server returns this:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT (@x:=@x+1) AS x, `ID` FROM realvalues) t WHERE x MOD 3 =' at line 2
```

the SQL command:

```
SET @x := 0;
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT (@x:=@x+1) AS x, `ID` FROM realvalues) t
WHERE x MOD 3 = 0;
```

Why does it work on SQLFiddle and does not work on my server?

Comment: Are you aware of that you cannot run multiple queries with single `mysql_query()` function ?

Comment: `mysql_query()` is identical to `mysqli::query()` and they both don't allow you to use multiple sql statements

Comment: thanks! I tried it via mysql console client and everything works. I cant accept your comment.

Comment: you can accept juergen's it avoids your problem with a single query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from 
(
  SELECT id, 
         @x := @x + 1 as rank
  FROM realvalues, (SELECT @x := 0) t
) a
where rank mod 3 = 0
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7af6/4)

Comment: Server returns this:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' @x := @x + 1 as rank FROM realvalues, (SELECT @x := 0) t WHERE x MOD' at line 1