# Select N roughly equidistant rows based on timestamp in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

The question was asked [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981024/select-equally-distant-rows-based-on-a-timestamp-column-in-mysql) but it appears from the discussion that the question had insufficient input to determine output. I have a similar problem. I will try to come up with some spec/logic.

I have a table with timestamp data that I have converted to unix_timestamp.

| id | p_value | ceil(unix_timestamp(updated_at)) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 300 | 1653549602 |
| 7 | 300 | 1653549902 |
| 11 | 300 | 1653550202 |
| 15 | 300 | 1653550502 |
| 19 | 300 | 1653550802 |
| 23 | 1200 | 1653551102 |
| 27 | 1300 | 1653551402 |
| 31 | 1300 | 1653551402 |
| 35 | 1300 | 1653551702 |
| 39 | 1300 | 1653551702 |

These are 10 rows with roughly equidistant times. And suppose I want `N` roughly equidistant rows. So I follow these steps for `N = 3`,

1. divide the set by `N - 1` i.e. `(max - min)/(N - 1)`. I get `2100/2 = 1050`
2. pick first row (with timestamp 1653549602) save as last
3. then pick (the first row with updated_at > (last + 1050)) i.e. with timestamp 1653550802 and save as last.
4. repeat step 3 until it crosses max; use max as last sample. i.e. with timestamp 1653551702.

I have this rough algorithm but how to write this in SQL.

**Sample output:**

| id | p_value | ceil(unix_timestamp(updated_at)) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 300 | 1653549602 |
| 19 | 300 | 1653550802 |
| 39 | 1300 | 1653551702 |

Comment: what do you mean by "N (= 3) roughly equidistant". In that mean you need a set of records which is equidistant to that Id = 3 record or what? I may be little confused with your requirement. How did you identify the "equidistant" data set among your Data set (what is the logic)?

Comment: Sorry about unclear explanation. I have updated the sentence. I want N rows.

Comment: "then pick (row with updated_at ≈ min + 1050) as last" <-- is this "as last" or "as second" ? can you show a sample of your output in a sample table or in a image

Comment: `last` is a variable saving last output as-in loop variable in procedural programming. The output of the example should pick row with id 3, 19, 39.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas, I am using mariadb 10.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just given a try. Check this can help you. Just try the function that i given.

1. Your '1653549602' is not the last. It is the first record that saved to table.

> 1653549602 = 2022-05-26 07:20:02 <-- first record 7:20
>
> and 1653551702 = 2022-05-26 07:55:02. <-- last record at 7:55

2. Also i feel there is a logic issue in your described scenario while selecting the last record. Because 1653550802 +  1050 mean real time is --> "2022-05-26 07:57:32". So you cannot select "1653551702" as the record through this condition **updated_at > (last + 1050))**.   1653551702 = "2022-05-26 07:55:02". So your condition not valid with it.

> 1653550802 + 1050 = 1653551852 which is "2022-05-26 07:57:32"
> So this condition is not working [ "2022-05-26 07:55:02" > "2022-05-26 07:57:32" ]

**[Start from here]**

Anyway i did a procedure for you. It give you a some idea to your requirement and also it will help you to go forward.

I used the same table structure as

```
create table `equidistants` (
    `pid` int (11),
    `id` int (11),
    `p_value` int (11),
    `unix_time` bigint (20)
);
```

pid is a column that i created as PK for me

Table name i used : **equidistants**

2. Created Below function

   ```
     DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_proc_equidistant;

     DELIMITER $$

     CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc_equidistant(IN n_value INT)
     BEGIN


        DECLARE i_val INT; -- Variable for (max - min)/(N - 1)
        DECLARE i_loop INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE i_Selected_unixTime INT;

        SET n_value = n_value -1;

        -- Handle the devided by 0 error
        IF n_value = 0 THEN 
            SET n_value = 1 ;
        END IF;

        -- (max - min)/(N - 1) calculate here
        SELECT  (MAX(unix_time) - MIN(unix_time))/(n_value) 
        INTO i_val FROM `equidistants` ; 

        -- Get the first updated value. Not the last one  
        SELECT unix_time INTO i_Selected_unixTime 
        FROM `equidistants`  ORDER BY unix_time ASC LIMIT 1; 

        -- Temporary table to keep your Data
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_equidistants; 

        -- Inser the latest record from the data set.
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_equidistants  
        SELECT * FROM equidistants  ORDER BY unix_time ASC LIMIT 1;

         -- Start the loop based on the given N value
         WHILE i_loop < n_value DO

            -- Insert the next selected record into the temp table base on the [last selected unix time + i_val]   
            INSERT INTO temp_equidistants 
            SELECT  *  FROM equidistants WHERE unix_time > i_Selected_unixTime + i_val  ORDER BY  unix_time ASC LIMIT 1;

            -- identify the next unix time 
            SELECT  unix_time INTO i_Selected_unixTime FROM equidistants WHERE unix_time > i_Selected_unixTime + i_val  ORDER BY  unix_time ASC LIMIT 1;

            SET i_loop=i_loop+1;
          END WHILE;

          -- Execute the result you need
          SELECT * FROM temp_equidistants; 

          -- Drop the Temp table
          DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_equidistants; 

     END$$

     DELIMITER ;
   ```

Hope you can do something with this function by modifying some areas.

4. Result that i got
   [image]

Note: 3rd record missing due to the condition miss match that i explain at the top

Here i used "ASC" for ther order by clause. You can change it to descending and you can run it other way-around.

Comment: I had mentioned in the 4th point that if the max value exceed the last row then select last row. So I added this check before the final select statement in your procedure,

 IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_equidistants) <= n_value THEN
    
    INSERT INTO temp_equidistants  
    SELECT * FROM `equidistants` ORDER BY unix_time DESC LIMIT 1;
 END IF;