# Select stratified sample from table without variables

Tags: mysql, sql, infinidb

I need to get a stratified sample of my huge table. Specifically, I want to select 1/n rows from my table *without bias*, i.e. select randomly, select every nth row, etc.

Before I asked this question, I tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858746/how-do-you-select-every-n-th-row-from-mysql). However, it didn't work for me because I am using the InfiniDB engine and, as I found out later, it doesn't support variables in sub-expressions, or something like that. Does anyone know a way to do this *without* user variables?

I was thinking about something like this: in my table, every row has a unique alphanumeric **string** id, which can look like `"1234567890"`, or like `"abcdef12345"`. I was thinking of somehow converting that string to a number, and then using the modulo function to only select 1/n rows from my table. However, I have no idea how to do the conversion, as this string is not hexadecimal.

Note: my table does *not* have an autoincremented column.

Comment: selecting every nth row is not random.

Comment: @DanBracuk True, but it's also completely unbiased and provides a stratified sample, which is what I want.

Comment: Is your alphanumeric string hexadecimal and completely contiguous?

Comment: @Arth no, sadly it's not hexadecimal. If, however, by contiguous you mean 'without spaces', then yes, it is.

Comment: How do you determine which alphanumeric string to give each value?

Comment: @Arth I'm not sure, but it's not autoincremented.

Comment: Just to clarify when you say 'without spaces' do you mean without space characters or that 'abcdef12345' will be followed by 'abcdef12346'? And which characters are permitted in your string?

Comment: @Arth I mean without space characters. As for the chars allowed, it's 0-9 and a-z (lower case).

Comment: Sorry, consecutive may have been a better word. If they are not consecutive, then how do you expect to get an integer value that increases by 1 for each row? Which is what you need for modulus in this case. Without an ability to generate a row number, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @Arth I don't want an integer value that increases by 1 each row. Why would I need that? All I need is for 2 different strings to always be assigned 2 different numbers.

Comment: @Bluefire, to use modulo you'd need it.. otherwise you'd have no idea how many rows you were returning. That's how both the suggestions work below.

Comment: @Arth right, but I don't need a precise amount of rows; that was made obvious by my willingness to randomise the selection. If I convert each string to a number and filter by modulo *n*, then I will select *approximately* 1 / *n* of the entries, which is fine.

Comment: @Bluefire Oh ok, that wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 3):

This is complicated, but you can do it.  It requires a self-join and aggregation, implemented in this query using a correlated subquery.  My guess is that this will not perform well, because you presumably have a large table.  For a 10% sample, it would look like:

```
select ht.*,
       (select count(*)
        from hugetable ht2
        where ht2.col < ht.col or
              (ht2.col = ht.col and ht2.id <= ht.id)
       ) as rn
from hugetable ht
having rn % 10 = 1;
```

Note that the use of `having` in this context is specific to MySQL.  It allows you to filter the rows without using a subquery.

EDIT:

Probably the only feasible approach -- it you can do it -- is to create another table with an auto-incremented id.  Here is a stripped down version:

```
create table temp (
    id int auto_increment,
    idstring varchar(255),
    col varchar(255)
);

insert into temp(idstring, col)
    select idstring, col
    from hugetable ht
    order by col;

select *
from temp
where id % 10 = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the first way, but the second one won't work because InfiniDB doesn't support constraints such as `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Where are you getting `ht1` from in the 1st approach? Shouldn't this be `ht`?

Comment: @Arth . . . Let's call that a typo.  It should be correlated with the outer alias, `ht`.