# Rails Active Record find every 10th record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm looking for a way to find every 10th record in my 'Lang' database starting with the first record. Something like this:

```
@words = Lang.find(records with ids of 1,11,21,31,41...)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you select every n-th row from mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858746/how-do-you-select-every-n-th-row-from-mysql)

Comment: @jvnill That question helps but its not active record its just mysql  but thanks it was a good starting point for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
total = Lang.count
ids = (1..total).step(10)
Lang.where(id: ids.to_a)
```

After thinking about this. 
I think if you are looking for a sample the best thing to do is

```
Lang.all.shuffle.first(30) # this returns 30 random rows from the langs table
```

I try to do it as clean as I could

I hope that this helps

Comment: how about a deleted record in that sequence ?

Comment: So lets say that row 11 is deleted then you want 13 or 21?

Comment: are you looking for just a random sample of records?

Comment: Lang.all.shuffle.first(10) # I think that this would work for what you are looking on doing

Comment: if my sequence has deleted record in between which may be 11, 12, i'll need 1,13, so on, it's just an example. deleted ids cannot be expected, the result should be dynamic.

Comment: Quit adding stupid contingencies in the comments, and ask a new question if you have one...