# MySql select every second, and third record from database

Tags: php, mysql

How can I select every second and third record from mysql database?
Here is sql I am using

This sql needs to select every second record:

```
$sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM test_db ORDER BY id DESC";
```

And this one needs to select every third record:

```
$sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM test_db ORDER BY id DESC";
```

I will try to explain my question better.
http://pokit.org/get/img/f202a616d0b5e8fe4c6c5875b9a668be.jpg
This would be my mysql database. Database name is test_db. How I can display every second record from this database where `LIMIT 2` and oreder by `DESC`?  Order needs to be like this `(44,15,6)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you select every n-th row from mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858746/how-do-you-select-every-n-th-row-from-mysql)

Comment: Do you need third rank or third row..?

Comment: I need every third record from mysql database.

Comment: Show example for every third row, second rows are so symmetrical. Do you mean 4->not, 6->not, 12->yeah, 15->not, 23->not, 44->yeah, 56->not and then order 44, 12? Or is it 56->no, 44->no, 23->yeah, 15->no, 12->no, 6->yeah?

Comment: So where are we with this question?

Comment: I really don't know how to explain more this question, I don't know how to set question ...

Answer (score 1):

You should define "every second record" more clearly. Every second is only reasonable if there is an order.

Do you mean the `id`?

Then it would be

```
select * from test_db where id % 2 == 0; // or id % 2 == 1
```

should it be every second in some other order?

Then I would go for (EDIT: order by needs to be inside subselect)

```
set @counter:=0;
select * from 
( select @counter:=@counter+1 as cnt, t.*
  from test_db as t
  order by inserted desc) as isel 
where cnt % 2 = 0;
```

Or if you want to sort by ascending id to find first row to throw away then use

```
set @counter:=0;
select * from 
( select @counter:=@counter+1 as cnt, t.*
  from test_db as t
  order by id) as isel 
where cnt % 2 = 0
order by id desc;
```

Or if you want to sort by descending id to find first row to throw away then use

```
set @counter:=0;
select * from 
( select @counter:=@counter+1 as cnt, t.*
  from test_db as t
  order by id desc) as isel 
where cnt % 2 = 0
;
```

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: @Riki What is the "first" row? MySQL has a kind of "natural" order, do you mean this order? Or is the lowest id the "first" row to throw away?

Comment: First record needs to have highest 'id', following records will have smaller id

Comment: So my sql should looks like this? `$sql = "set @counter:=0;
select * from 
( select @counter:=@counter+1 as cnt, t.*
  from test_db as t
  order by id desc) as isel 
where cnt % 2 = 0
;"; `

Comment: When i run that i got an error `Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\prodaja\index.php on line 85`

Comment: The first query (`set @counter:=0`) is like an update, so not `select`- like, I think you need a different `mysqli_` method.

Comment: Can you write me code because I am afraid i do not understeant.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using `mod`.

For every 2, 4, 6, record:

`SELECT * FROM test_db WHERE mod(id, 2) <> '1';`

And for odd number of rows (1,3,5,7) to be fetched:

`SELECT * FROM test_db WHERE mod(id, 2) <> '0';`

[1st SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8caf3/3)

**EDIT:**

As per the changes you mentioned in the comment, this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, id
    FROM (
        SELECT @row :=0) r, test_db
    ) ranked
WHERE rownum %4 =1
```

[2nd SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b9cc/1)

**Second EDIT:**

After reading your edited question, a few changes made and this should be fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, id
    FROM (
        SELECT @row :=0) r, test_db
    ) ranked
WHERE rownum %2 = 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

[3rd SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b9cc/8)

Comment: Thank you really much, that solved my problem. Can you tell me how it would be to select record in order like this (1,5,9,13) ?

Comment: Can you check my question again. I editted it. Thanks

Comment: @Riki Check if it fulfills your requirements?

Comment: Your edit is good but can you add "LIMIT 5" and "DESC" In that code? I get error while trying.

Comment: @Riki  I have added `DESC` and `LIMIT 5` kindly run the 3rd SQL Fiddle.