# How to get the X'th most recent SQL query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm using the google charts API to create a graph. I have 48 data points, a point for every 30 minutes in a day. My php script runs every 15 seconds and saves the calculated Bitcoin Price to a database. Right now to get the most recent price from the database, I am using this code.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT priceLBTC FROM prices ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$bitcoinPrice = 0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $bitcoinPrice = round($row["priceLBTC"], 2);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

    $sql2 = "SELECT priceLBTC FROM prices ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5760";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql);
    $bitcoinPriceArr = array();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        $i=-1;
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $i++;
            if ($i%120) continue;

            $bitcoinPriceArr[] = round($row["priceLBTC"], 2);
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }


$conn->close();
?>
```

So the first data point on the graph should be the most recent price, which is $bitcoinPrice, and then the 47 following data points should be the 120 rows before one another. ex: the id of the next data point is ((row of the most recent price) - 120)). (php script runs every 15 seconds, so 4 times a minute * 30 minutes = 120 times every 30 minutes)

Is there an easier way to get all that data and put it into the chart without creating 47 other variables and querying them individually?

Here is the relevant google chart javascript

```
function drawAxisTickColors() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Price');

            data.addRows([
    [0, 0],    [1, 10],   [2, <?php echo $bitcoinPriceArr[0]; ?>],  [3, 17],   [4, 18],  [5, 9],
    [6, 11],   [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35], [12, 35], [13, 35], [14, 35], [15, 35], [16, 35], [17, 35], [18, 35], [19, 35], [20, 35], [21, 35], [22, 35], [23, 35],
    [24, 5], [25, 5], [26, 5], [27, 5], [28, 5], [29, 5], [30, 5], [31, 5], [32, 5], [33, 5], [34, 5], [35, 5], [36, 5], [37, 5], [38, 5], [39, 5], [40, 31], [41, 320], [42, 315], [43, 305],
    [44, 299], [45, 309], [46, 300], [47, <?php echo $bitcoinPrice; ?>]
  ]);
```

Comment: I'm still having trouble adding the data from the array into the google chart api in javascript.

Comment: Your question stated that you needed help with the sql query or the parsing of its results. Extending your request to a whole new topic isnt very polite. I added the PHP-to-JS part and how to use it for the Google Chart to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the forum before just posting a question.

This is basically explained here: [How do you select every n-th row from mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858746/how-do-you-select-every-n-th-row-from-mysql)

Applied to your usecase that would be something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, priceLBTC 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT @row :=0) r, prices 
    ) ranked 
WHERE rownum % [120] = 1
```

An easier - and maybe even more performant - way though, would be just getting all of the data and cherry pick the points you need with PHP.

```
$sql = "SELECT priceLBTC FROM prices ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5760";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$bitcoinPrice = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $i=-1;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $i++;
        if ($i%120) continue;

        $bitcoinPrice[] = round($row["priceLBTC"], 2);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}


$conn->close();
```

What happens is:

- Limit is set to 48 times 120 requests (5760: the maximum for 24 hours)
- `$bitcoinPrice` should be an `array`, since it needs to hold a couple of values
- `$i=0` after the first iteration
- From there on, only data points are picked for which `$i` leaves no
  remainder after division by 120

Even better would be to get all queried results at once via `mysqli::fetch_all` and build the `$bitcoinPrice` array by only getting every 120th entry. This way you would not have to loop through 119 data points just to get the one you need.

**ADD:**

You turn a php variable into something usable in  javscript with `json_encode($bitcoinPriceArr)`. If you echo the result of that in an javascript assignemnt you will end up with a javascript array:

```
var bitcoinPrizes = <?php echo json_encode($bitcoinPriceArr); ?>;
```

With that you can build your chart:

```
var rows=[];

for (var i in bitcoinPrizes ){
    rows.push([i, bitcoinPrizes [i]]);
}

data.addRows($rows);
```

I assume you could also do:

```
for (var i in bitcoinPrizes ){
    data.addRows([[i, bitcoinPrizes [i]]);
}
```

But I am not entirely sure there.

Pleae keep in mind that this is no place to get your whole tasks sorted out and solved. Hire a developer for that.
If you have a specific question or run into a concrete problem, you may ask for help here.
But it is still up to you to learn the very basics of the languages and technologies you use.

Comment: Won't almost 6000 sql queries slow the web page down considerably?

Comment: its not 6000 queries; its one query with 6000 records. But you have both approaches in front of you and can try it yourself. Usually SQL performance goes down considerably as soon as you start more complex operations. Maybe here the SQL way is the smarter choice. Just try it out. But as a rue of thumb: logic should be taken of in a proper programming language.

Comment: Ok. I tried the second option and fed one of the array values into the google chart javascript portion with no luck. Updated the OP with my new code.

Comment: Shouldnt the code inside the while loop be $bitcoinPriceArr[$i] = round($row["priceLBTC"], 2);

Comment: nope $bitcoinPriceArr[$i] would add a value at the index $i. But since you lieave out a lot of indexes you would end up with indexes like 0, 120, 240... that would not actually be a problem and you could normalize it later. But with $bitcoinPriceArr[] you always add a new element with a properly iterated index to the array.