# get next row of current mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this:

```
ID NAME
1 juan
2 pedro
3 jose
4 lucas
5 antoni
```

I need show result like this:

```
1 juan
3 jose
5 antoni
```

How should I proceed to show every record in a sequence of 2 ?
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858746/how-do-you-select-every-n-th-row-from-mysql duplicate

Comment: In your example Lucas is 4, but in the example results he is 3... what's the reasoning there?

Comment: I was wrong, it was 3 -> jose

Comment: in this case the sequential is 2, but in another moment the sequential will be 3 or 4, then the result like: 1 juan ,   4 lucas

Answer (score 3):

Use `Modulo(%)` operator

```
Select * from yourtable Where ID % 2 = 1
```

This considers `ID` is sequential

Comment: Won't deleted records affect this solution though?

Comment: My initial thought from his/her results example was thinking he/she wanted odds as well, but looking at the title, it seems he/she wants every next row (though I'm not sure how order is deduced or matters)

Comment: @Abdul The OP hasn't indicated that that's a problem

Comment: @Strawberry Understood. I misread "next row" as every other row

Comment: @Strawberry at the same time, if I understand secuencia to mean sequence, I interpret his/her statement of "The secuencia is 2." as meaning records in sequence of two or every other row, as I had initially interpreted it. Thus deleting a record would place either an even ID or odd ID next to each other, in which the result set for this solution would not return "every other row"

Comment: and if the ID not is sequential??

Comment: @jantoni in that case, I'd loop through the table or use a cursor and manually skip every other iteration, and place them into a table variable or temp table. I'm not too experienced with SQL though, so I'm not sure if that's the best solution

Comment: thank you, i need too show rows with sequential 3,4,5, etc

Comment: @Abdul Yes, but until the OP clarifies their requirements, we have no way of knowing which is the right strategy. The OP could easily have connstructed a more comprehensive dataset. They chose not to.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM 
 (
 SELECT ID,NAME,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC)as ROW
 FROM TABLE
 ) as A
 WHERE ROW % 2 = 0
```

Comment: Is in Mysql bro, than you