# Mysql / Eloquent - return every 3 rows

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this query :

```
$b = Class::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(50)->get();
```

This gets me the last 50 elements in my table . However i only want every 3 rows e.g : valu1 , value3 , value5 , value6

Is there a way to process that directly in the sql query without additional code ?

Thanks

- Does not have to be eloquent , could be an sql query that does the same as above.

Thanks

Comment: May be you are looking for some thing like this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858746/how-do-you-select-every-n-th-row-from-mysql

Comment: What do you want actually, 1th, 4th, 7th row in the data or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Laravel of latest versions:

```
$b = Class::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->nth(3)->get();
```

More about [nth()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-nth)